# Add two list of strings together in KDB

Tags: kdb

I am trying to add two lists of strings together.
for example:

firstName: William
Joseph
Charles
David
Michael
William

lastName: Jones
Brown
Johnson
Rodriguez
Rodriguez
Wilson

and I want a `full_name` list. How could I do that?

I have tried simply adding a comma

```
full_name:firstName,lastName
```

and

```
full_name:""sv(firstName;lastName)
```

but these seem only work with single string not list.

Does anyone know how to sum 2 list and get a third one?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be good if you were to post an example of exactly of what you're looking for. Also, in general, it's not good practice to use `_` in variable names as it can be mistaken for the `drop` operator

One way of achieving a list of full names would be splitting both lists on the `" "` separator using `vs` then flipping the results and zipping them together using the `sv` operator.
This will only work if there are as many elements in lastName as in fullName.

```
q)firstName:"William Joseph Charles David Michael William"
q)lastName:"Jones Brown Johnson Rodriguez Rodriguez Wilson"
q)show fullName:" " sv' flip " " vs' (firstName;lastName)
"William Jones"
"Joseph Brown"
"Charles Johnson"
"David Rodriguez"
"Michael Rodriguez"
"William Wilson"
```

Answer (score 1):

If firstName and lastName are already same-length lists of strings of the form:

```
q)("William";"Joseph";"Charles")
"William"
"Joseph"
"Charles"
```

then you can use the each iterator to do this, like so:

```
firstName {" " sv (x;y)}' lastName
```